# Add cmd line options when parent option is defined in python argparse

Tags: python

Add parent related cmd line options when parent option is defined in python argparse.

Ex:
script.py -project project1 [-owner subba -created_on 20/09/2015]
In the above example i want to add the other two arguments when user entered project option in the cmd line. like conditional based argument. If user entered other parent command, Need to add cmdline options related to that command.

Comment: Do you mean you need conditionally required arguments? That is -owner and -created_on should only be used when -project is also used?

Comment: Yes. When user defines -project argument, I want to add the other two arguments to the script. Else those are arguments are not added to script.

Comment: You mean you want to add them manually? Not the user specifying them?

Comment: Let me explain in a very clear way. There are 100 cmd line options. divided into 10 parts of options. All the argument details are stored in one file. When user defines the parent argument, i want to add the arguments in a dynamic way those associated 10 arguments. The remaining i do not want to add to the script. Based upon the parent argument selected by the user, the parent associated arguments will be displayed in the script. In the script i have parent name and its associated arguments that part i have taken care.

Comment: Ex: -project project1 [the remaining arguments pick from file.]